# I have a problem. How do I combine all my materials into 1 materials (Material Atlasing)? (My 3Dmodel screenshot attached)?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

So I have a problem in combining all of my materials into one. When I do UV unwrap and bake them, I end up with an abomination resembling the picture attached. Can somebody please tell me what I did wrong?[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not a core feature and doing this by hand could be very time-consuming, so I'm recommending this addon: https://blendermarket.com/products/texture-atlas-generator it's $3.50, but it can save you hours of work.

Comment: and what you're doing wrong: Need a ton more information, my best guess is you're baking to the wrong UV Map.